# Ошибка при создании таблицы с MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

Работаю с БД MySQL. При попытки создания таблицы, выявляется ошибка, что не так?

Код:

```
table = 'test'

    ConnectSQL = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
        user='root',
        password='7LvuoK8UGV',
        db='sqlmngrbot',
        charset='utf8mb4',
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

    with ConnectSQL:

        CursorSQL = ConnectSQL.cursor()
        CursorSQL.execute("CREATE TABLE %s (chat_id INT, owner_id INT, title VARCHAR(255));", table)
```

Ошибка:

```
  File "c:/Users/Степан/Desktop/ManagerBot/run.py", line 29, in <module>
    createChatForSQL(vk, chat_id)
  File "c:\Users\Степан\Desktop\ManagerBot\functions.py", line 49, in createChatForSQL
    CursorSQL.execute("CREATE TABLE %s (chat_id INT, owner_id INT, title VARCHAR(255));", table)
  File "C:\Users\Степан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\Степан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\Степан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 517, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "C:\Users\Степан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 732, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "C:\Users\Степан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1075, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "C:\Users\Степан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 684, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "C:\Users\Степан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\protocol.py", line 220, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "C:\Users\Степан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line 109, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''test' (chat_id INT, owner_id INT, title VARCHAR(255))' at line 1")
PS C:\Users\Степан\Desktop\ManagerBot>
```

Comment: Имя таблицы - литерал, он не может быть параметром.

Comment: @Akina, зачем вводить в заблуждение? Если не знаете / помните что такое литерал - можете прочитать здесь. Имя таблицы не может быть литералом в SQL запросе. Литералы как раз могут быть параметризированы. PS можно конечно динамически собрать SQL запрос, где имя таблицы будет литералом или переменной, но это тема для отдельного вопроса/разговора...

Comment: @MaxU *Если не знаете / помните что такое литерал* Литерал - это то, что не может измениться. Фиксированное значение. Имя таблицы в тексте запроса - литерал. *Имя таблицы не может быть литералом в SQL запросе.* Имя таблицы в тексте запроса (и вообще любой алиас) - литерал. А не строковый литерал, который параметризуется. Так же, как, к примеру, границы у LIMIT...

Comment: @Akina, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/literals.html

Comment: @MaxU Угу, практически русским по белому написано - Literal **values**.

Comment: @Akina, серьезно?? Вы не понимаете чем отличаются “identifiers” от “literals” в SQL?

Comment: @MaxU Identifier - это объект. Так что да - имя таблицы есть и identifier тоже. Впрочем, боюсь, что насчёт терминологии мы не договоримся, потому что этот момент нигде и никак не описывается. И я что-то навскидку не вижу иного способа в одно слово определить, что некий идентификатор в тексте запроса не может быть результатом вычисления/подстановки во время исполнения (константа и т.п. - увы, не подходит). Может, предлОжите вариант?

Comment: @MaxU Для проверки на прочность - в моей (пусть будет "моей") терминологии параметр(ы) `LIMIT` является литералом в обычном запросе, но не является таковым в динамическом запросе.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101915/discussion-between-maxu-and-akina).

Comment: @Akina, в моем представлении всё наоборот. Любое слово в динамическом запросе можно считать литералом или частью строкового литерала, а в обычном запросе литералами я считаю конкретные значения - числа, строки, обрамлённые одинарными кавычками и т.д.

Comment: [Определение "literal" в Oracle DB - `The terms literal and constant value are synonymous and refer to a fixed data value.`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ)